# Array size in Java

Tags: java, memory-management

What would be the memory size/space occupied in bits/bytes by array as follows.

```
final String[] objects_user1={"1","10","100","1000","10000"};
```

Comment: I hope this isn't for a live test or interview....

Comment: Cant be for an interview since you dont need to know really

Comment: Unless you're talking about a specific JVM implementation on a specific architecture, you can really only come up with an estimate. There is nothing in the specs that say precisely how much storage anything will take in Java.

Comment: Also you can try [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip130.html).

Comment: I am trying to calculate the performance of a device and running the code on it. I want to create objects of different size and then retrieve them, thus calculate the throughput.

Comment: @user357349 What do you mean by "retrieve them"? Is it the serialized size you're interested in?

Answer (score 4):

ROUGH ESTIMATE: 12 bytes for array header, 4x5 bytes for the pointers (8x5 if you're on a 64 bit jvm), each string has 3 ints (+3x4 bytes), and an array of chars (+12 bytes for header + length of the string x2, because it's char).

Comment: Yeah, I wonder that too. I think if peole are going to downvote, they should at least tell you why. I'll give you an upvote to cancel it out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to Google it? Here is [the first result](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml) of my Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say, since its an implementation detail of the JRE you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an approximate answer by querying available heap space before & after the memory allocation. Run it a number of times & compute the average, & it will be pretty close to the right answer. But again, the answer is only valid for the specific JVM it's run on.